# Split algorithm on a string list

Tags: python

im looking for a way to generate a split alogrithm with any random string list and an expected output string. The expected output string will have an ":" seperator everytime.

```
import re

to_split = """
'email = "foo@mail.com, info = "lalsdfaslsad"))'
'email = "bar@mail.com, info = "lasdfl1241aslsad"))'
'email = "foooo@3robosa.com, info = "lalsdfsdfas241lsad"))'
'email = "foooodf@sdfrobosa.com, info = "ladsfsdflas241lsad"))'
'email = "foooo@dsdfrobosa.com, info = "lalas241lsad"))'
'email = "foooo@ferobosa.com, info = "lalas241lsad"))'
'email = "foooo@rodbosa.com, info = "lalas241lsad"))'
'email = "foooo@rodsfa.com, info = "laldsfsdfas241lsad"))'
""".splitlines()


def split_it(s, e):
    ms = 10
    for line in s:
        for item in e.split(':'):
            if line.find(item) != -1:
                l_chars = re.escape(line[line.rfind(item) - ms:line.rfind(item)])
                r_chars = re.escape(line[line.rfind(item) + len(item):line.rfind(item) + len(item) + ms])

                if l_chars and r_chars:
                    for line2 in s:
                        regex = r'{}(.+?){}'.format(l_chars, r_chars)
                        if re.search(regex, line2):
                            print re.search(regex, line2).group(1)


expected_output = 'foo@mail.com:lalsdfaslsad'
split_it(to_split, expected_output)
```

Current Output:

```
foo@mail.com
bar@mail.com
foooo@3robosa.com
foooodf@sdfrobosa.com
foooo@dsdfrobosa.com
foooo@ferobosa.com
foooo@rodbosa.com
foooo@rodsfa.com
lalsdfaslsad
lasdfl1241aslsad
lalsdfsdfas241lsad
ladsfsdflas241lsad
lalas241lsad
lalas241lsad
lalas241lsad
laldsfsdfas241lsad
```

Expected output:

```
foo@mail.com:lalsdfaslsad
bar@mail.com:lasdfl1241aslsad
foooo@3robosa.com:lalsdfsdfas241lsad
foooodf@sdfrobosa.com:ladsfsdflas241lsad
...
```

Thank you guys in advance

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate each email with its 'info'??

Comment: why are there 3 " in the string - thats unbalanced - me eyes huuuuuurt

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 'email = "foo@mail.com, info = "lalsdfaslsad"))'
a = a.split(", ")
print ":".join([a[0].split("=")[-1],  a[1].split("=")[-1]]).replace("))", "").replace('"', "")
```

**Result:**

```
"foo@mail.com: lalsdfaslsad
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that "to_split" won't be the same format everytime. Also the "expected_output" variable is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` to capture all text that appears after the `=` and join with the desired `:`:

```
import re
to_split = """
 'email = "foo@mail.com, info = "lalsdfaslsad"))'
 'email = "bar@mail.com, info = "lasdfl1241aslsad"))'
 'email = "foooo@3robosa.com, info = "lalsdfsdfas241lsad"))'
 'email = "foooodf@sdfrobosa.com, info = "ladsfsdflas241lsad"))'
 'email = "foooo@dsdfrobosa.com, info = "lalas241lsad"))'
 'email = "foooo@ferobosa.com, info = "lalas241lsad"))'
 'email = "foooo@rodbosa.com, info = "lalas241lsad"))'
 'email = "foooo@rodsfa.com, info = "laldsfsdfas241lsad"))'
 """
new_l = '\n'.join(filter(None, [':'.join(re.findall('(?<=\s\=\s")[a-zA-Z@\.]+', i[:-2])) for i in filter(None, to_split.split('\n'))]))
print(new_l)
```

Output:

```
foo@mail.com:lalsdfaslsad
bar@mail.com:lasdfl
foooo@:lalsdfsdfas
foooodf@sdfrobosa.com:ladsfsdflas
foooo@dsdfrobosa.com:lalas
foooo@ferobosa.com:lalas
foooo@rodbosa.com:lalas
foooo@rodsfa.com:laldsfsdfas
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that "to_split" won't be the same format everytime. Also the "expected_output" variable is needed.

Comment: @Sansch I changed the output to reflex the `expected_output`. However, if `to_split` may vary, what would those variances look like?

Comment: Basically im trying to parse different types of databases. So im trying to match one item with the expected_output, grab the split conditions and use it on all lines.